# Set date value with JS

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm trying to give a default value with JS to a data input type in HTML, but the value is not setted.
This is the HTML tag:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="economic_data_date" name="Economic Data Date" required="True"/>
```

This is the JS code:

```
function insert_economic_data(month){
    var m = "12";
    var d = "31";
    if (month == 'April'){
        var origin_url = window.location.origin;
        window.location.replace(origin_url.concat("/my/economic_data/insert_economic_data"));
        var y = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
        var today = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
        document.getElementById("economic_data_date").value = today;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the template with the value not setted.
[image]

Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: do you confirm the function is called? check if it is invoked after document rendered.

Comment: Add some validation to your script.  You call several functions, assuming the returns are correct, check the returns and types.

Answer (score 0):

[`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) triggers a page load, meaning that no changes you make to the *current* page's DOM will survive, because a new page is being loaded.

Instead, you'll have to pass the information to the *new* page, and have it fill in the date field.

Answer (score 0):

You are only filling the date field, if the month is `April`. You need to put the lines

```
    var y = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
    var today = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    document.getElementById("economic_data_date").value = today;
```

outside the if statement.

```
function insert_economic_data(month){
    var m = "12";
    var d = "31";
    if (month == 'April'){
        var origin_url = window.location.origin;
        window.location.replace(origin_url.concat("/my/economic_data/insert_economic_data"));
    }
    var y = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
    var today = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    document.getElementById("economic_data_date").value = today;
}
```

Comment: How do you know they don't *want* to only do this when `month == 'April'`?